# javascript 変数の中で継承を行う方法が知りたい。

Tags: javascript

提示コードの`///`コメント部内部のコードなのですが、上の`Component`を親クラスとして子クラス`Renderer`クラスを生成したいのですが以下のエラーが出ますこれはなぜでしょうか？

###### 試したこと

コメント部内部のように実験

###### エラー

```
FrameWork.js:46 Uncaught ReferenceError: Component is not defined
    at FrameWork.js:46:38
(anonymous) @ FrameWork.js:46
Script.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'GameObject')
    at Script.js:4:32
(anonymous) @ Script.js:4
Script.js:33 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'GameObject')
    at setup (Script.js:33:27)
    at p5._setup (p5.js:62985:27)
    at p5._start (p5.js:62908:25)
    at new p5 (p5.js:63261:22)
    at _globalInit (p5.js:62189:17)
setup @ Script.js:33
_setup @ p5.js:62985
_start @ p5.js:62908
p5 @ p5.js:63261
_globalInit @ p5.js:62189
Promise.then (async)
280.../core/main @ p5.js:62214
o @ p5.js:34
(anonymous) @ p5.js:38
267../accessibility/color_namer @ p5.js:54831
o @ p5.js:34
r @ p5.js:51
(anonymous) @ p5.js:55
(anonymous) @ p5.js:18
(anonymous) @ p5.js:20
```

```js
"use strict"

var FrameWork = 
{
    


    /*##########################################################
    # GameObject
    説明
    シーンに存在するオブジェクト
    ############################################################*/
    GameObject : class GameObject 
    {
        constructor()
        {

        } 
    },
    
    /*##########################################################
    # Component
    説明
    シーンに存在するオブジェクト
    ############################################################*/
    Component : class Component
    {
        constructor()
        {

        } 

        Update()
        {
            alert('オーバーライドされていません。');

        }
    },

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /*##########################################################
    # Renderer
    説明
    レンダリング
    ############################################################*/
    Renderer: class Renderer extends Component
    //Renderer: class Renderer extends Component.Component
    //Renderer: class Renderer extends FrameWork.Component.Component
    {
        constructor()
        {
            super();
        }




    },
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /*##########################################################
    # Transform
    説明
    座標、回転、スケール
    ############################################################*/
    Transform : class Transform
    {
        constructor()
        {
            this.position = 
            {
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
            };        
            
            this.scale = 
            {
                x: 1.0,
                y: 1.0,
            };        

            this.rotate = 0.0;

        } 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

一般化すると「オブジェクトリテラルの中でプロパティを定義するとき、同一オブジェクトの他のプロパティを参照するには?」ということなのですが、現在の JavaScript ではできないようです。何らかの方法で遅延させる必要があります。

一番簡単なのは、いったんオブジェクトリテラルを閉じて、プロパティを代入することでしょう。

```js
const framework = {
  Component: class {
    constructor() {}
    Update() {}
  },
  // Rendererはこの中では定義しない
};
// 外で代入する
framework.Renderer = class extends framework.Component {
  constructor() { super(); }
};
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問ですが名前空間をJSで利用する場合質問文のようなコードは正解なのでしょうか？名前の衝突を避けたいのですが。描画ライブラリです。

Comment: 別の質問だと思うので、新しい質問を立ててください

Answer (score 3):

そもそもの目的は名前空間を作りたいという話ではないでしょうか？そうであれば、XY問題になっています。今時、オブジェクトを使用して名前空間を作るなんてことは誰もしません。

現在のJavaScriptで名前空間を作る場合は[モジュール](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)を使います。モジュールではファイル毎に名前空間が作成されます。`export`で外部から使えるように宣言された変数・関数・クラス等を`import`で読み込みます。`import`時に何をどのような名前で読み込むのかを指定します。`import`で指定されていない、または、そもそも`export`されていない変数・関数・クラス等は`import`している側から見えません。このような仕組みにより、名前が衝突しているかどうかの判断がファイル内で完結できるようになっています。(ただし、グローバル変数を変更しているようなJSを`ipmort`した場合は、グローバル変数への副作用が発生します。)

モジュールについて詳しく述べるとさらに長くなるためあとは割愛しますが、仕組み的にはPythonのモジュールに近いです。C++の`namespace`のような名前空間の考え方が全く違いますので、参考にしてはいけません。